# Drop Oracle Schema Scott?

Tags: oracle11g, database-schema

Sorry if this question is stupid or has been answered, but I can't find a yes or no anywhere.

In our **Production Oracle** environment, **is it ok to drop schema SCOTT**?

I know its a sample schema, but our security department wants to remove any user that isn't in use. Get nervous dropping users that were installed by the OUI. There are objects in there that aren't from OUI, so I've backed up this information just to be safe.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's safe. Oracle even ships a script to delete all sample schema: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC110

Comment: Thanks! The first thing I did a while back was Expire and Lock the user, was going to DROP USER SCOTT CASCADE, but I'll give this a shot in our Dev environment since it's recommended practice.

Answer (score 2):

SCOTT schema is used by some applications to test the db or to install a simple demo (eg. Mondrian OLAP) or to make the reference for performance tuning.

On production DB (I'm not a DBA) we don't have got SCOTT.

However, a good practice (on DB, LDAP, AD..) is to disable user (instead of delete):

```
ALTER USER user_name ACCOUNT LOCK/UNLOCK
```

IMHO, you can delete!

Answer (score 0):

it is not stupid question !
you can unlock it , because scott schema is usable for some of tasks in database

Comment: The question is not if the account can be unlocked, the question was if the user can be dropped entirely